# handling multiple formats of data file (JSON, XML, CSV)

Tags: pipeline, apache-beam

If data comes in various file formats in one single object storage bucket. Should this handled with one single pipeline? what is the best practice?

Answer (score 0):

It will depend on if your requirements include join/merge data from different formats.

Say if you have multiple sources and each source reads data for a file format. And then you want to do a flatten to merge your PCollections and does aggregations, you have to have one single pipeline.

You can also check[1], [2], [3].

There is [4] that shows how BeamSQL convert from text file to Row.

[1]https://beam.apache.org/documentation/pipelines/design-your-pipeline/#multiple-sources
[2]https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/java/core/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/schemas/Schema.java
[3]https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/java/core/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/values/Row.java
[4]https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/java/extensions/sql/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/extensions/sql/meta/provider/text/TextTable.java#L68

Comment: Thanks much Rui. So the source is same, one single bucket, pipeline will treat a specific format as a specific source then flatten to merge PCollections. Should I include an intermediary step to transform all formats (CSV, XML) to JSON and let beam handle just one format? What is the best practice?

Comment: I see. I am familiar with Schema and Row in Beam. So I would imagine I could have multiple sources in one pipeline, and each source processes one file format in bucket to Row in Beam, and then do further processing on PCollection of Row.

Comment: In BeamSQL, it allows you create multiple text table, each table has its format (cvs, etc.). BeamSQL compiles each text table to a source, read form source and convert whaterever format to Row, and then does normal SQL processing.

Comment: To add to Rui's comments, I don't believe there's a single best practice based on what you described. It depends on what you want to do with that data. E.g. if you need to group the elements together, then it's probably easier to do if you keep them in the same `PCollection` from the start. In this case I would probably have one `ParDo` that parses all elements into a single common format. But if you're just transforming the elements one-by-one then it doesn't matter much from Beam's perspective, but it may be easier to get better parallelism if you had multiple sources in this case (or not).